# Check if tag of an image exists in a docker registry using shell script

Tags: arrays, json, bash, docker, shell

I have a list of images and their respective tags in a given `images.json` file, like below:

```json
{
  "image1":"1.1",
  "image2": "1.2",
  "image3": "1.3"
}
```

I was able to use a sed command to read values from above `images.json` and store each column in an array , such as

```sh
image=${arraydata[0]}
tag=${arraydata[1]}
```

For each image, I would like to compare if its tag exists in the below output I get from a curl command:

```sh
curl -X GET https://docker.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/docker/docker-local/v2/$image/tags/list?
```

Output of above:

```json
{
  "name" : "image1",
  "tags" : [ "1.1", "1.2" ]
}{
  "name" : "image2",
  "tags" : [ "1.1", "1.2", "1.3" ]
}{
  "name" : "image3",
  "tags" : [ "1.1", "1.2", "1.4" ]
}
```

I would like to have an if/else statement to check if tag for an image exists in the results above:

- If exists then do nothing
- Else do `docker push jfrog/$image:$tag`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps (untested)

- assumes your shell is [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)
- uses [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) for your JSON-parsing needs

```sh
declare -A versions
while IFS=$'\t' read -r img ver; do
    versions[$img]=$ver
done < <(
    jq -r '. as $obj | keys[] | [., $obj[.]] | @tsv' images.json
)

# versions=([image1]="1.1" [image2]="1.2" [image3]="1.3" )

for img in "${!versions[@]}"; do
    ver=${versions[$img]}
    url="https://docker.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/docker/docker-local/v2/$img/tags/list?"

    artifacts=$(curl -X GET "$url")
    result=$(jq --arg ver "$ver" '.tags | contains([$ver])' <<<"$artifacts")

    if [[ $result == true ]]; then
        echo "image $img has version $ver"
    else
        echo "image $img does not have version $ver"
    fi
done
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I tested it and threw me an error "jq: error (at <stdin>:6): null (null) and array (["1.0.19\r"]) cannot have their containment checked. Assuming i already got image:tag from json file in an array. can you probably help in checking if input tag value exists in the curl command output for an image? using same if else method

Comment: What's that carriage return doing in there?

Comment: honestly I could not understand your script . since some images like image2 have more than 1 versions ( 1.1 , 1.2 , 1.3) in my json file. i would like it to check each against curl output

Comment: Update your question with all the relevant requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
status=$(wget --spider --server-response http://any_url:5000/v2/repository/image-name-you-query/manifests/latests 2>&1 | grep "HTTP/" | awk '{print $2}')
```

This snipped will print 200 if the image exists and something else if tehre is any problem. Particularly, if it does not exist, you will get 404.

You can then leverage this in your shell script like this:

```
if [ $status -eq 200 ]; then
    # do something
else
    # do something else
fi
```